# How to animate mixer / tumbler in blender

Tags: physics

[image]Hi Blenderers, I want to animate a cube containing "beans" , how it rotates on one axis like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qhwm5pEBVfU

I made my model with physics but when the beans fall on the surface of the cube they don't follow the rotation. this is the problem, how to make them tumble/mix around in the cube and which settings to use. My file http://www.mediafire.com/file/bfv86466zdhmva1/mixing__motion.blend/file

Best Regards,
Alex